# What kind of language do I learn if I want my client to be able to update the site?

Tags: html, scripting

I'm creating a website where I'd like the client to be able to add articles, images, and audio clips without having to edit the code of the website.

For example; on the sidebar of the site, there's 3 audio clips (they're demos of music) with images and text to go along with them. I'd like for them to be able to change all of those things at any time.

Comment: Any server sided language. PHP is reasonably easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any language that is server-side can be used. This includes, but is not limited to, Python, Ruby, and PHP. This question is otherwise too broad to give a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a CMS (content management system) like Drupal. Your client will have access to a nice web interface to manage the site content.

Comment: 's response is the best unless you really want to program the entire site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any server side Language like,PHP,JSP/Servlet,ASP.NET etc.
PHP will be easier for implementation.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you want standard html and javascript.

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) would help aid the design process and [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) would aid the coding.